# How upgrade to latest glibc on BeagleBone Black using opkg (or otherwise)

Tags: upgrade, glibc, beagleboneblack, opkg

I have glibc version 2.15 on my BeagleBone Black. I want version 2.19, but I don't know how to upgrade to the newest version. `opkg list-upgradable` doesn't print anything. What should I do?

```
root@am335x-evm:/lib# ls -la | grep libc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        888940 May  2  2013 libc-2.15.so
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Mar 31 02:33 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.15.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this part is not an easy task but here are few methods to upgrade package on linux embedded device.

1) Method:
Download glibc-2.19 debian package on to device (either directly using curl or download onto PC and scp to the device)
(download the debian package based on your architecture type 32/64 bit)

Use Opkg module to install the new glibc package,

```
opkg -f /etc/opkg.conf -d ram update 
opkg -f /etc/opkg.conf -d ram install <package-name>
```

Note:
a) verify the opkg configuration file
b) below is sample of config file

```
src/gz repo <package-repository-url>

dest ram /tmp
lists_dir ext /var/opkg-lists
option overlay_root /overlay
arch all 100
arch armv7l 200
arch armel 300
```

2) Method:

If you have internet on beagle bone then refer below links and you can find some command format examples.

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg

http://wiki.blue-panel.com/index.php/OPKG_%28en%29

3) Method:

Download the package source files on to your linux PC and cross-compile to beagle bone.
And then scp all required files of the package(binary,config files.....)